# how to filter multiple rows in listview in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi am doing one app here i need  to display cloumns in lisview,and i have to set search(filter)action to that listview,i tried using below code that is almost working fine,in filter function i am getting problem in edit text if enter first letter means it shows below listview it shows that letter related names,but it showing in both columns  what ever e enter that letter related names,but my want if enter letter means that time i need to filter only based first column names,if enter ? with any letter that i need to filter  names based 2 column.please any one having idea suggest me...

```
     ListMobileActivity.class: 
    public class ListMobileActivity extends Activity {EditText edittext;
 ListView listview;
 String qustion="?";

 String[] text = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
 "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };

 String[] text1 = { "udya", "aswini", "radha", "padma", "ram", "harish", "parasd",
         "adi", "harbinder", "pandu" };


 int textlength = 0;
 ArrayList<String> text_sort = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> text_sort1 = new ArrayList<String>();


 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);

 edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
 listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
 listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text, text1));
 edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
 {

 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
 {

 }

 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
 int count, int after)
 {

 }

 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
 int before, int count)
 {

 textlength = edittext.getText().length();
 text_sort.clear();
 text_sort1.clear();

 for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
 {



 if (textlength <= text[i].length())
 {

 if (edittext.getText().toString().
 equalsIgnoreCase((String) text1[i].subSequence(0, textlength)))
 {
 text_sort.add(text[i]);
 text_sort1.add(text1[i]);

 }

     if ((edittext.getText().toString()).

     equalsIgnoreCase((String) text[i].subSequence(0,textlength)))
     {
     text_sort.add(text[i]);
     text_sort1.add(text1[i]);

     } 




 }
 }

 listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter
 (text_sort, text_sort1));

 }
 });
 }

 class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
 {

 String[] data_text;
 String[] data_text1;


 MyCustomAdapter()
 {

 }

 MyCustomAdapter(String[] text, String[] text1)
 {
 data_text = text;
 data_text1 = text1;

 }
 MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> text, ArrayList<String> text1)
 {
 data_text = new String[text.size()];
 data_text1 = new String[text1.size()];


 for(int i=0;i<text.size();i++)
 {
 data_text[i] = text.get(i);
 data_text1[i] = text1.get(i);

 }

 }

 public int getCount()
 {
 return data_text.length;
 }

 public String getItem(int position)
 {
 return null;
 }

 public long getItemId(int position)
 {
 return position;
 }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
 {

 LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
 View row;

 row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

 TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
 TextView textview1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);


 textview.setText(data_text[position]);
 textview1.setText(data_text1[position]);

 textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String sss=qustion.concat(edittext.getText().toString());
        Log.i("sss--------------", ""+sss);
    }
});

 return (row);

 }
 }
  }
```

Comment: hi i got answer using this link http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/07/android-search-in-custom-listview.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try out this example

[Listview names search in Android](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/buttons-on-list-view-with-easy-searching-in-android/)

Here you can search the list item names by simply typing in the edittext

Comment: thankyou.my code also working every thing.my problem is if i click "a" means that time it showing all "a"related names in both columns.but what i want is if  type "a" in edittext i need display first column "a" related names only not second column related names

Comment: and if i press "?a" that time i need to display or show only second column related names not first column related names

Comment: you can see this [example](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/12/28/image-search-in-the-listview-in-android/)

Comment: like the above example, you can set string array in place of drawable(integer) array

Comment: hi sory how i tried ur code pls can u let me "?a" means how to sort based on 2 array

Comment: in the `et.addTextChangedListener()....change the condition if(yoursecondarray[i].toLowerCase().contains(et.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim()))....Try like this

Comment: if (edittext.getText().toString().
  equalsIgnoreCase((String) text1[i].subSequence(0, textlength-1))) i tried like this if i enter blackslash am getting error